# Error: "Android log was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to load an old c project (for android 5.1, API 22) in the Android studio 2.2. The source code includes using the android logger. When I build the project in the studio. The studio reports some errors:

```
Error:(34, 21) error: '__android_log' was not declared in this scope
Information:(84, 5) in expansion of macro 'LOGD'
Warning:(35, 79) warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 10 has type 'void*' [-Wformat=]
Information:(91, 9) in expansion of macro 'LOGI'
Error:(34, 35) error: expected ';' before '_print'
Information:(102, 5) in expansion of macro 'LOGD'
Error:(34, 21) error: '__android_log' was not declared in this scope
Information:(107, 5) in expansion of macro 'LOGD'
...
```

I tried to add log library into the Gradle script

```
productFlavors {
    fat {
        dimension "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            versionCode = 0;
            ldLibs.addAll(["log"]) // <- not working
        }
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    armv7a {
        dimension "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi"
            versionCode = 1;
            ldLibs "log" // <- not working neither
        }
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```

But the studio reports error: `Error:(71, 0) Could not get unknown property 'ldLibs' for ProductFlavor_Decorated`.

Anyone knows how to add log library in android studio 2.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because there isn't actually an android-22 in the NDK. Android 5.1 didn't have any new native APIs, so the NDK doesn't have the directory. Try setting `targetSdkVersion` to 21?

Really important thing to note: when using the NDK, your target API level is your minimum API level. I believe Gradle does not enforce this, but it's very likely that native code will not run on a device below the target API level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dan. I tried to change the targetSdkVersion to 21. But still having same build errors. I also checked the ndk-bundle/platforms/android-22/<ABI>/lib the liblog.so is there. So I think the issue must be caused by missing so Gradle configures.